# Understanding matplotlib subplot indexing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have tried unsuccessfully to create a matplotlib figure layout using add-subplot().

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(layout='constrained', figsize=(8, 5))
fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 2)
fig.add_subplot(3, 1, 3)
fig.add_subplot(3, 2, 4)

fig2, axs = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['d', 'd']],
    layout='constrained', figsize=(8, 5))
plt.show()
```

'fig2' shows what I wanted to achieve.
I'm not so much interested in the solution as in an explanation of the index system for add_subplot().
thanks Linus

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the indexing of subplots work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971541/how-does-the-indexing-of-subplots-work)

Comment: I think to get the layout you want with `add_subplot` you can't use integer indexing but need to [arange the subplots on a gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_multicolumn.html).

Comment: @RuthC: thanks you for this link above: It's very close but yet another indexing system.